# c# create a .bacpac file from ms sql database

Tags: c#

I try to create a bacpac File from my complete Database.

I added `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` and created a `DacService`. And on the service I call the `ExportBacpac` method. But I always get the error that the Database Source is not supported Version of SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = txtServerStart.Text;
csb.Password = txtPassword.Text;
csb.UserID = txtUserName.Text;

DacServices ds = new DacServices(csb.ConnectionString);
ds.ExportBacpac(@"C:\backup\backup.bacpac" + txtFilename.Text, cbDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

The error comes on the line where I call the `ExportBacpac` method.

Comment: perhaps because .bacpac is only supported by SQL Databases on Azure. Is your database on Azure or on-premise?

Comment: @VivekJain - on what do you base that claim? I just connected to a local DB using SSMS, selected a database, Right-clicked, chose `Tasks -> Export Data-Tier Application`, went through a wizard and it created a `.bacpac` file for me. (Server/SSMS are 2012, no reason to believe it's not possible on other versions though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was i am using MS SQL Server 2016 and the Version of the Dac DLL´s was to old. i used 12.xxxxx but i need 13.xxxxxx

After i referenced these DLL's it works fine